# PHP_SELF failing

Tags: php, html, forms

Here is my abridged single-page html/php code for a form with one user input - name. Once the submit button is clicked I want the page to display the user input or the relevant error message, but this is not occurring. Could you please have a look over my code and determine why it is failing to submit to self?

index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php 
$nameErr = "";
$name = "";

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $nameErr = "Name is required";
  } else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
      $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
  }
}
?>

<div class="form-group" id="form">    
<center>
<form name="form" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>">
<fieldset>
<legend>Enquiry</legend>
<table width="400px"><tr><td valign="top">
<label for="name">Name*</label></td>
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>" maxlength="50" size="30">
<span class="error">*<?php echo $nameErr;?></span></tr></td>

<tr><td colspan="2">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</tr></td></table></form>

<?php
echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
echo $name;
?>


</div></fieldset></body></html>
```

Comment: Where does it submit? What does the `action` contain when the page loads?

Comment: You can leave the `action` attribute blank; it defaults to using the same URL.

Comment: Also no need to check the request method AND if the post is empty.

Comment: @miken32 Sure there is. What if the user leaves the field empty before submitting?

Comment: You're missing a `}` at the end of the first `if()`.

Comment: @chris85 When I click submit, a new page loads with "Not Found. The requested URL /< was not found on this server." I'm previewing it on 000webhost.com and they claim to support php. I've also tried action= "" and __DIR__ and__FILE__, based on other info I've found on stackoverflow, none of which worked either.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Maybe the issue is not with my code but with how I'm trying to preview it. When I upload the above code as a php file to 000webhost.com, nothing loads. In order to preview my form it needs to be a html file - I'd expect this to work because php can be embedded within html. But if this isn't the case and the code has to be in a php file then how can I view it? Are there any text editors that support previews of html+php files?

Comment: @Barmar Nice one, thanks. It would just go at the end of the block, correct?

Comment: Yes. When I added it to your code, the page worked fine for me.

Comment: @NatalieAnna Lots of web development IDEs can preview the page, e.g. PhpStorm.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, I've got it previewing on PhpStorm now but when I click submit it still gives me a 404 Not Found error, any ideas?

Comment: Not sure, I've never actually tried to use the PhpStorm built-in webserver.

Comment: All good, thanks again!

Comment: If you;ve got it all fixed please close the question so other user, like myself, don't come looking to answer your question.

Comment: @WinterRoberts It's not fixed. My form's still refusing to submit to self and I don't understand why.

Comment: If you just change the action to the pages name like `action="index.php"` or whatever your page name is does it work then?